# MultiThread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote a program in Java using multithreading and inter-thread communication. In my program, the producer is a teacher who writes a line on the board, and my consumers are the students who will read the line written by the teacher. They inform the teacher with a count variable as a flag so that he/she can wait and then get notified to move ahead. Here is the program I wrote for the same:

```
package Multi;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Excersie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WhiteBoard wb=new WhiteBoard();
        teacher t=new teacher(wb);
        Students s=new Students("Jhon",wb);
        Students s1=new Students("Ajay",wb);
        Students s2=new Students("Kloob",wb);
        Students s3=new Students("Smith",wb);
        t.start();
        s.start();
        s1.start();
        s2.start();
        s3.start();
    }
}
class WhiteBoard{
    String Text;
    int noOfStudents=0;
    int count=0; 
    public void attendence()
    {
        noOfStudents++;
    }
    synchronized public void write(String WROTE)//For the teacher (Producer)
    {
        System.out.println("Teacher is Writting:"+WROTE);
        while(count!=0){try{wait();}catch(Exception e){}}//Here we are demanding for count is zero as if the noofstudents isn't the zero that means teacher can't write thus wait
        Text=WROTE;
        count=noOfStudents;//No of Students reamaining
        notifyAll();
    }
    synchronized public void read()//For the Students(Consumer)
    //Synchronized as it only allows one thread at a time 
    {
        while(count==0){try{wait();}catch(Exception e){}}//count ==0 means the teacher is writng on the board
        System.out.println("Read "+count+":"+Text);
        count--;
        if(count==0)
        notify();
    }
}
class teacher extends Thread{
    WhiteBoard wb;
    teacher(WhiteBoard b)
    {
        wb=b;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=1;
        while(i<=10)
        {
            
            System.out.print("Enter the Text to we written:");
            String msg=sc.nextLine();
            
            wb.write(msg);

           i++;
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}

class Students extends Thread{
    WhiteBoard wb;
    String name;
    Students(String n,WhiteBoard b)
    {
        wb=b;
        name=n;
        wb.attendence();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        wb.read();
    }
}
```

However, when I run it for the first time, it works fine. After that, the threads get mixed up and start to behave in a random order. How do I fix it?
Here's the output:

```
Enter the Text to be written :y
Teacher is Writing: y
Enter the Text to we written :Read 4:y
Read 3:y
Read 2:y
Read 1:y
34
Teacher is Writting:34
Enter the Text to we written:45
Teacher is Writting:45
```

The output i want:

```
Enter the Text to be written :Hello
Teacher is Writing: Hello
Read 4:Hello
Read 3:Hello
Read 2:Hello
Read 1:Hello
Enter the Text to be written :World!
Teacher is Writing: World!
Read 4:World!
Read 3:World!
Read 2:World!
Read 1:World!
Enter the Text to be written ::)))
Teacher is Writing: :)))
Read 4::)))
Read 3::)))
Read 2::)))
Read 1::)))
```

The above text pattern for the number of times the loop is executed.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @mttdbrd as in i want that ,first the teacher writes some text on white board then all thee students must write it until then all the student threads must wait and once the teacher is finished writing students must read it ,until then the  teacher must wait

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the output that you **want** to get. Also, are you aware of the various [concurrency classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html) in the JDK?

Comment: I have edited the question. Actually i have just finished the basics of multithreading ,and i don't know about those

Comment: Your students read one thing and then just stop. You need to put a `while` loop in either `Students`' `run()` method, or in the `read()` method.

Comment: **Style note:** Some of the behavior of a "teacher" is embodied in your `Whiteboard.write()` method, and virtually _all_ of what it means to be a "student" is embodied by your `Whiteboard.read()` method. You might want to think about how you could organize the project in a more object-oriented way, where the code that defines what it means to be "teacher" is contained entirely within the `Teacher` class, code that defines "student" is kept inside the `Student` class, and the methods and fields of the `Whiteboard` class only define what it means to be a "whiteboard."